# Организация связи между двумя wi-fi модулями

Tags: wifi, arduino

Возникла необходимость создания односторонней связи между двумя wi-fi модулями. Сами модули - lolin nodemcu v3. Задача простая: с одного модуля в непрерывном цикле постоянно пересылать какие-то данные на второй модуль. Все это дело делается на ардуине. На вопрос "а зачем это все?" отвечаю - просто эксперимент. Задача решена на радиомодулях, на bluetooth, но качество связи не устраивает, решил попробовать на wi-fi. Я посмотрел, очень много информации по данному модулю lolin nodemcu v3, как что там делается, но мне это все не очень интересно разбираться в такой огромной куче информации. Поэтому хочу просто у вас спросить, как такая связь организовывается, какой-то алгоритм. Насколько я понимаю, на принимающей стороне нужно поднять сервер, с другой стороны к нему прицепиться и как-то пересылать данные. Или есть какие-то варианты проще? Что касалось радиоканала и bluetooth, так там это две строчки кода с одной и другой стороны. А когда коснулся wi-fi, то это оказалось все не таким простым, как мне представлялось. Прошу помощи, чтобы понять хотя бы в какую сторону копать и что мне на самом деле необходимо для моей задачи

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для вашего случая идеально подойдет UDP протокол:
Подключение:

```js
bool Connection() {

  if (WIFI_ENABLE) {
    SendWiFiLog("WiFi:Try connect...");
    WiFiManager wifiManager;

    //Disable debug log connection
    wifiManager.setDebugOutput(false);
    wifiManager.setAPCallback(configModeCallback);
    wifiManager.setSaveConfigCallback(saveConfigCallback);

    /**
     * if we couldn't connected to save WiFi access point
     * we will start our own access point with ip address 192.168.1.4
     */
    wifiManager.autoConnect("AP: AquaController");
    Udp.begin(localUdpPort);
    broadcastAddress = (uint32_t) WiFi.localIP() | ~((uint32_t) WiFi.subnetMask());
    SendWifiIp(true, true);
    return true;
  } else {
    SendWiFiLog("WiFi:Disable...");
    return false;
  }
}
```

Отправка пакета:

```js
void SendSuccesMessage(String message, bool isBroadcast) {
 if (!WIFI_ENABLE) {
  SendWiFiLog("WiFi:Disable...");
 }
 if (isError) {

  return;
 }
 if (isBroadcast)
  Udp.beginPacket(broadcastAddress, localUdpPort);
 else
  Udp.beginPacket(Udp.remoteIP(), Udp.remotePort());
 Udp.println(message);
 Udp.endPacket();
}
```

Чтение пакетов:

```js
void loop() {

 if (WIFI_ENABLE && !isError) {
  if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED) {
   int packetSize = Udp.parsePacket();
   if (packetSize) {
    int len = Udp.read(incomingPacket, MAX_BUFFER);
    if (len > 0) {
     if (len > MAX_BUFFER) {
      len = MAX_BUFFER;
     }
     incomingPacket[len] = 0;
    }
    isWaitResponse = SendRequestToUART(incomingPacket);
    memset(incomingPacket, 0, sizeof(incomingPacket));
    if (!isWaitResponse) {
     return;
    }
   }
  }
 }
```

Библиотеки:

```js
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>
#include <WiFiManager.h>
```

Осталось сесть и разобраться...